# constrains of return distribution and risk return trade off

Tags: portfolio-optimization, risk, distribution

Suppose we have a portfolio $V$, we are only allowed to invest in one stock $S$, its price movement follows the geometric brownian motion, i.e. $dS=S(\mu dt+\sigma dW)$. We are allowed to choose different  gearing ratio $\lambda(V,S,t)$ which depends on portfolio value, stock price and time. Suppose risk free rate is 0 for simplicity, since we are net longing $S$, our portfolio sharpe ratio is same as $S$, which is $\mu/\sigma$ regardless of $\lambda$. But the return distribution is different between different gearing ratios. What are the constrains of return distributions? Certainly we can't have a return distribution like $P(x)=\{^{0,x<V_0}_{\frac{1}{1+x^3},x>V_0}$, no matter how we choose the gearing ratio. What else can't we have?

Also how do we compare different investments? Comparing sharpe ratio is one way but $P(x)$ has a sharpe ratio of 0, finite mean return, but it never loses. What about median return? A portfolio with high $\lambda$ will have a high mean return, but low (possibly negative) median return.

Another real life example is longing SPXL vs shorting SPXS. They have the same sharpe ratio because the underlying asset is SPX for both of them. The return distribution of longing SPXL is a log-normal distribution, and the distribution of shorting SPXS is a reflected log-normal distribution over the y-axis. And shorting SPXS has a higher median return. The difference between mean and median return is sometimes referred as "volatility decay", which some people tend to avoid.